# iterating over a dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over this dictionary

```
let interestingNumbers = [
"Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
"Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
"Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
```

I want to **keep track of the largest number in this dictionary and the name of key corresponding to this number**

Here is my code :

```
var largest = 0
var largestName: String?

for (names, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        for name in names {
            if number > largest {
                largest = number
                largestName = interestingNumbers(forKey: largest)
            }
        }

    }
}
print(largest)
print(largestName)
```

but I'm getting this type of error : `error: cannot call value of non-function type '[String : [Int]]'`

I don't know where I missed the proper iteration. Any help plz. Thank you

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `forKey`? That's not how it's done in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a print of `names` and `numbers` directly in the outer loop you will realise there is no need to loop over `names` as you do and neither is it necessary to try to use the dictionary again inside the loop.

So we could skip one loop ands directly use the `names` variable to remember the name of the largest value array. And furthermore there is no reason to loop over the `numbers` array either since Array has a `max()` function we can use.

So the code becomes

```
for (names, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    if let max = numbers.max(), max > largest {
        largest = max
        largestName = names
    }
}
```

An even short way to do it is to use some high-order functions to get the max value

```
interestingNumbers.mapValues({ $0.max() ?? 0 }).max(by: { $0.value < $1.value})
```

This will return a tuple and can be used like this

```
if let tuple = interestingNumbers.mapValues({ $0.max() ?? 0 }).max(by: { $0.value < $1.value})  {
    largest = tuple.1
    largestName = tuple.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code.

First of all, you have an extra loop - `for name in names` iterates over each character of the `Dictionary` keys. The outermost `for ... in interestingNumbers` already gives back the key-value pairs of the dictionary.

You simply need to iterate over `numbers` to find the max element of each array, then assign the correct number and the key (`name`) to your variables.

```
for (name, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestName = name
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's even better to use functional programming and first find the max value from each array using `compactMap`, then find the maximum out of each key-value pair using `max(by:)`

```
let largestNumbers = interestingNumbers.compactMap { pair -> (String, Int)? in
    guard let max = pair.value.max() else { return nil }
    return (pair.key, max)
}
let largest = largestNumbers.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })

largest // ("Square", 25)
```